# Iterator variable behaving strangely in C++

Tags: c++

So I am somewhat new to the intricacies of C++ and its memory handling.

I wrote a piece of code in which the iterator in main function is not behaving as i would expect. It is supposed to take `n` inputs instead it is just exiting midway depending on the values inputted. The `mergeSort` and `merge` function works just fine (at least for small arrays with predefined elements) so no need to check that. The main problem is in the `main` function. Any help would be appreciated.

```c++
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

 void merge(long int *a, long int start, long int mid, long int end)
 {
    long int *c=new long int[1000000];
    long int i,ptr1=0,ptr2=0,ptr=0;
    long int length1,length2;
    length1=mid-start+1;
    length2=end-mid;
    while(ptr1<length1 && ptr2<length2){
        if(a[start+ptr1]>a[mid+ptr2+1]){
            c[start+ptr]=a[mid+ptr2+1];
            ptr++;
            ptr2++;
         }
        else if(a[start+ptr1]<=a[mid+ptr2+1]){
            c[start+ptr]=a[start+ptr1];
            ptr++;
            ptr1++;
         }
     }

    while(ptr1<length1){
        c[start+ptr]=a[start+ptr1];
        ptr++;
        ptr1++;
    }
    while(ptr2<length2){
        c[start+ptr]=a[mid+ptr2+1];
        ptr++;
        ptr2++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<ptr; i++)
      a[start+i]=c[start+i];

 }


 void mergeSort(long int *a, long int start, long int end){

    if(start<end){
        long int mid;
        mid=(start+end)/2;
        mergeSort(a, start, mid);
        mergeSort(a,mid+1, end);
        merge(a, start, mid, end);
     }
 }

 /*Problem lies in Main*/

 int main()
 {
    string s;
    int n,i,j;
    long int *a=new long int[1000000]();
    cin >> n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){                             /************Loop exiting midway************/
        cin >> s;
        stringstream g(s);
        g >> n;
        a[i]=n;
     }
    mergeSort(a,0,n-1);
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
        cout << a[j] << "\n";
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Forgive me for bad formatting of code.

Comment: *Forgive me for bad formatting of code.* -- Why do you need all of that code if the issue is with the `for` loop in `main()`?  Next time, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Code format is hugely improved by setting language correctly.

Comment: Aside: C++ has *never* required you to declare all your variables at the top of the function. It is **much** clearer to define them in exactly the scope you need them, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }`. Also you'd do better with re-arranging it to `cin >> n; std::vector<long int> a(n);`

Comment: @Caleth actually i just switched from using C and i haven't yet unlocked the power of  c++11 so i am still not using all the useful libraries till i understand it completely

Comment: `std::vector` is part of the *original* standard library. C++ is a **different language** to C, code *should* look different. `vector` is a drop-in replacement for dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g >> n;` in the loop is the cause. You overwrite `n` and thus it fails the loop condition midway.

Simply use `cin >> a[i];` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks mate...just completely missed it

Comment: Actually i was wondering the purpose of `stringstream`, `cin >> a[i]` should work just fine. @DuttaA

Comment: the value inputted is a string of an integer

Comment: Isn't `n` input in the same way? @DuttaA

Comment: ya i completely somehow missed it